# free(): invalid next size (fast) string too long?

Tags: c, string, memory-management, free, glibc

My code is getting the following error:

```
free(): invalid next size (fast)
```

My code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>


  int main()
  {  
char *temp_str;
char *pos, *pos2;
char *key = (char*)malloc(20);
char *data = (char*)malloc(20);
const char newline = '\n';

char *unparsed_data = "NEW_DATA_PACKET\n\
  Data Set 16-byte Universal Key\n\
  Unix Time Stamp (microsecs): 1319639501097446\n\
  Frame Number: 0\n\
  Version: 3\n\
  Platform Yaw Angle (deg): 15.22428\n\
  Platform Pitch Angle (deg): 1.78528\n\
  Platform Roll Angle (deg): 2.004111\n\
  Image Source Source: test\n\
  Image Coordinate System: Testing XXXXX\n\
  Sample Latitude (deg): 17.306791\n\
  Sample Longitude (deg): -60.26209\n\
  Sample True Altitude (m): 7.623407\n\
  Sample Horizontal FoV (deg): 0.1821277\n\
  Sample Vertical FoV (deg): 15.1879\n\
  Sample Rel. Azimuth Angle (deg): 291.70295\n\
  Sample Rel. Elevation Angle (deg): -5.941163\n\
  Sample Rel. Roll Angle (deg): 3.10959\n\
  Checksum: 4659\n";

temp_str = (char*)malloc(strlen(unparsed_data));

printf("\nThe original string is: \n%s\n",unparsed_data);

//Ignore the first two lines
pos = strchr(unparsed_data, newline);
strcpy(temp_str, pos+1);
pos = strchr(temp_str, newline);
strcpy(temp_str, pos+1);
printf("STARTING THE PARSER\n\n");
while(strlen(temp_str) > 2)
{
  printf("\tstarting loop\n");
  //Getting the position of the colon and newline character
  pos = strchr(temp_str, ':'); // ':' divides the name from the value
  pos2 = strchr(temp_str, '\n'); //end of the line
  realloc(key, (pos-temp_str-1)); //allocate enough memory
  realloc(data, (pos2-pos)-1);

  printf("After realloc \n");

  //copying into key and data
  strncpy(key, temp_str, (pos-temp_str));
  strncpy(data, pos + 2, (pos2-pos)-2);

  //Append null terminator
  strcpy(key+(pos-temp_str-1)+1, "");
  strcpy(data+(pos2-pos)-2, "");


  printf("%s = ",key);
  printf("%s\n",data);

  assign_value(key,data, &gvals);

  printf("The value has been assigned\n");
  strcpy(temp_str, pos2+1);

  printf("Freeing key and data\n\n");

  free(key);
  free(data);

}

return 0;
  }
```

I am also getting some garbage when it is printing

```
STARTING THE PARSER

    starting loop
After realloc 
Unix Time Stamp (m13196395 = 13196395
The value has been assigned
Freeing key and data

*** glibc detected *** ./memory_alloc: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x098cd008 ***
```

Finally, when I reduce the length of the lines of the string, the code works perfectly. It works fine with the following string:

```
char *unparsed_data = "NEW_DATA_PACKET\n\
  Data Set 16-byte Universal Key\n\
  Time Stamp: 1319639501097446\n\
  Frame Number: 0\n\
  Version: 3\n\
  Yaw Angle: 15.22428\n\
  Pitch Angle: 0.78528\n\
  Roll Angle: 2.004111\n\
  Source: test\n\
  Coor System: Test XXXXX\n\
  Latitude: 27.306791\n\
  Longitude: -60.26209\n\
  True Altitude: 7.623407\n\
  Hor FoV: 0.1821277\n\
  Ver FoV: 15.1879\n\
  Azimuth: 291.702954\n\
  Elevation: -0.433563\n\
  Roll: 0.79659\n\
  Checksum: 2659\n";
```

** ****Solution:**** **

```
int main()
      {  
    char *temp_str;
    char *pos, *pos2;
    char *key = (char*)malloc(20);
    char *data = (char*)malloc(20);
    const char newline = '\n';

    char *unparsed_data = "NEW_DATA_PACKET\n\
The UAS Datalink Local Data Set 16-byte Universal Key\n\
Time Stamp: 1319639501097446\n\
Frame Number: 0\n\
Version: 3\n\
Yaw Angle: 15.22428\n\
Pitch Angle: 0.78528\n\
Roll Angle: 2.004111\n\
Source: test\n\
Coor System: Test XXXXX\n\
Latitude: 27.306791\n\
Longitude: -60.26209\n\
True Altitude: 7.623407\n\
Hor FoV: 0.1821277\n\
Ver FoV: 15.1879\n\
Azimuth: 291.702954\n\
Elevation: -0.433563\n\
Roll: 0.79659\n\
Checksum: 2659\n";


    temp_str = (char*)malloc(strlen(unparsed_data));

    //Ignore the first two lines
    pos = strchr(unparsed_data, newline);
    strcpy(temp_str, pos+1);
    pos = strchr(temp_str, newline);
    strcpy(temp_str, pos+1);
    printf("STARTING THE PARSER\n\n");
    while(strlen(temp_str) > 2)
    {
      printf("\tstarting loop\n");
      //Getting the position of the colon and newline character
      pos = strchr(temp_str, ':'); // ':' divides the name from the value
      pos2 = strchr(temp_str, '\n'); //end of the line
      char *new_key = (char*)realloc(key, (pos-temp_str+1)); //allocate enough memory
      char *new_data = (char*)realloc(data, (pos2-pos+1));


      if(new_key)
        key = new_key;
      if(new_data)
        data = new_data;

      printf("After realloc \n");

      //copying into key and data
      strncpy(key, temp_str, (pos-temp_str));
      strncpy(data, pos + 2, (pos2-pos)-2);

      //Append null terminator
      memset(key + (pos-temp_str) , '\0', 1);
      memset(data + (pos2 - pos), '\0', 1);


      printf("%s = ",key);
      printf("%s\n",data);

      assign_value(key,data, &gvals);

      printf("The value has been assigned\n");
      strcpy(temp_str, pos2+1);

      printf("Freeing key and data\n\n");

      free(key); key= NULL;
      free(data); data = NULL;

    }

    return 0;
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the mistake:

```
realloc(key, (pos-temp_str-1)); //allocate enough memory
realloc(data, (pos2-pos)-1);
```

`realloc()` returns the address of the new buffer (which may be different), with the buffer that was passed in potentially being deallocated. The old buffers are then passed to `free()`, but they may have already been deallocated. You need to save the return value from `realloc()`:

```
char* new_key = realloc(key, ...); /* Don't assign key = realloc(key, ...);
                                      Since if realloc() fails it returns
                                      NULL, but leaves the original
                                      buffer unmodified. This will
                                      result in a memory leak. */
if (new_key)
{
    key = new_key;
}

free(key);
key = NULL; /* Be sure assign key to NULL, otherwise dangling pointer will
               be passed to realloc() on next iteration. */
```

Also, see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Great! It worked, thanks. I also used part of @wallyk solution, and used memset to append the null terminator.

Comment: I also read about casting realloc, but I was getting `invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]`

Answer (score 1):

There are subtle problems in this code:

```
realloc(key, (pos-temp_str-1)); //allocate enough memory
realloc(data, (pos2-pos)-1);

  ...
strncpy(key, temp_str, (pos-temp_str));
strncpy(data, pos + 2, (pos2-pos)-2);
```

The reallocated length is n-1, but it copies n characters to it.  This would be better:

```
key = realloc(key, pos - temp_str + 1);
memset (key, 0, pos - temp_str + 1);  // make sure terminating NUL present

data = realloc(data, pos2 - pos + 1);
memset (data, 0, pos2 - pos + 1);
   ...
strncpy(key, temp_str, pos - temp_str);
strncpy(data, pos + 2, pos2 - pos - 2);
```

Comment: Um, you missed the much bigger problem. OP is throwing away the return value of `realloc`.

Comment: Also, note that `strncpy()` will not NULL terminate the destination if there's not a NULL within the first `n` characters of the source.

Comment: `ptr = realloc(ptr,newsize);` is always a mistake. If the realloc fails, the old block of memory is leaked.

Comment: Thanks wallyk. I used both your solution and @hmjd solution